# Not able to target button in modalbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open the following webpage (https://www.nike.com/nl/nl_nl) and target/click the "JA, IK ACCEPTEER ZE" button. Which basically says: Yes I want to allow cookies.

But I simply cannot get selenium to target the button.
I tried the obvious as seen below. Why doesn't this work and how to fix it?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome();
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/nl/nl_nl");
driver.findElement(By.LinkText("JA, IK ACCEPTEER ZE")).click();
```

**Update:**

Below is the code I tried, sorry it was listed as Java. I guess it did that automatically???

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/nl/nl_nl/')

try:
    cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR("button.yes-button")));   

finally:
    driver.close()
```

This gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Nike.py", line 11, in 
>      EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR("button.yes-button")));
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: The best is to combine the answer of DebanjanB for the WebDriverWait and JeffC for the CSS selector. So: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.yes-button"))).click();

Comment: Can you share your code and show us where you get this TypeError?

Comment: @Frank I added my code, sorry it was listed as Java, can't remember doing that :S.

Comment: The number of parenthesis is odd, one right parenthesis to much.

Answer (score 0):

`By.linkText()` operates on text contained in an **anchor** (like `<a href...`) tag.

You probably want: `By.xpath("//button[text()='JA, IK ACCEPTEER ZE']")`.

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @RémonvanNieuwenhuizen Sorry, I am not familiar with Python error reporting. I thought the question was for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simpler and more generic with a CSS selector instead of targetting the button by contained text. The CSS selector below will find the "YES, I ACCEPT" or "JA, IK ACCEPTEER ZE" button no matter the language and I've confirmed it's unique on the page.

```
button.yes-button
```

From looking at the site, you will likely need a wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.yes-button"))).click()
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You'll have to post your code. That error message is a python error message from what I've seen and you have this question tagged as Java.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember adding java :S. I added my tried python code in an update!

Comment: There is a problem with your syntax. See my update. Also reference the python docs, http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to open the following webpage (https://www.nike.com/nl/nl_nl) and click the button with text as **JA, IK ACCEPTEER ZE** which is within a modal box you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button.wide"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='nsg-button nsg-grad--nike-orange yes-button cookie-settings-button js-yes-button wide']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @RémonvanNieuwenhuizen Thats pretty much weird. Can you please provide me the error stack trace generated executing my command?

Comment: I added my tried python code and the error in an update.